# What to put on RAMDisk on Windows?

Tags: windows, memory, cache, ramdisk

I got a lot of RAM installed in my PC recently and I looked into this RAMDisk thing.

There are two things I've found from my investigation:

1. You should not mess with Windows native pagefile/memory settings. Memory handling system of Windows and its services are perfected by multiple years of testing in real scenarios. SuperFetch and Windows memory model apparently make moving specific files and folders to RAMDisk unreasonable since mapped files are not immediately flushed from memory and SuperFetch does a good job of predicting user's actions.
2. However, developers of 3rd party programs like browsers and utilities spent considerably less time worrying about performance, thus in edge cases, like having an abundance of memory, these program work in a less than optimal ways.

If I am correct, RAMDisk may be useful to store some programs' temporary cache: the files that can be automatically regenerated without much trouble. Browsers love to cache data to disk to avoid downloading it from internet, what else can be put on RAMDisk?

Comment: Just about anything.

I'm a developer and use a 1-2GB RAM disk for holding the working copy of code bases I work on. The time taken to build a typical app is reduced by about a factor of 10 compared to conventional HD and even SSD. Highly recommended if you've got the spare RAM.

Answer (score 6):

"What to put on RAMDisk on Windows?" A: ***Nothing.***

A RAMdisk is a foolish use of RAM.*

Windows, esp in Vista and later, will do a perfectly good job of using "extra" RAM for file and page cache. It does this completely automatically. And if a process suddenly turns out to need that some of that RAM-that-once-was-"extra", the OS can take it back from these caches just about instantly (only marginally slower than when it uses "free" RAM) and let the process that needs it, use it. It will do so intelligently, first repurposing low-priority cache that hasn't been accessed in a long time.

Whereas... When you lock RAM away in a RAMdisk the OS then can't *ever* use it for actual "live" contents (i.e. to resolve page faults), not in *any* amount of time. That's bad.

Practically all claims that "the OS isn't managing my RAM well" are due to misinformation about how virtual memory works and what it does, and misinterpretations of various displays. (Granted, Microsoft has not helped much here.)

(* The only exception I'll agree to is if you're running e.g. 32-bit Windows clients, which just won't look at more than about 3 GB of RAM. A RAMdisk product that makes use of RAM the OS flatly can't or won't use doesn't take anything away from the OS. A better long-term answer is of course to go to an OS that *will* use of all of your RAM.)

Comment: This is not a very good answer. There are numerous scenarios where a Ramdisk is a great use of RAM.

Comment: On a primitive OS that truly leaves the "available" RAM unused, perhaps. On a modern OS? No, there aren't, for all the reasons I described... especially since SSDs have become large and cheap.

Comment: Okay here's a scenario for you: I'm running a virtualized, encrypted Windows 7 from a linux live usb. Both linux and win running USB 2.0, since that's all this computer has. It works but the drives are so slow it constantly locks up ... except if I put the programs on a RamDisk. I have plenty of RAM to do so, and like this it's perfectly usable. So you're saying a Ramdisk is useless, this setup would not work without one. Of course if I had the latest super computer, there would be other solutions, but we're talking real life here and RAMdisks are an excellent tool for certain things.

Comment: "Hey, swimming with a brick in each hand is tough! Oh wait, I know - I'll use an innertube to help me float!" Uh, ok... but dropping the bricks would be much more effective.

Comment: funny but sometimes you have no choice but to swim with a brick in each hand. There are also many other scenarios requiring the high performance of a RAMDisk. Last time I checked RAM was still thousands of times faster than the best SSD out there. If you had said "In most cases, A Ramdisk is not useful to increase performance on a modern machine with an SSD" instead of a categorical "RAMDisk is a foolish use of RAM" I would agree with you.

Comment: Ignorant. Automating the use of RAM vs disk can never be fully done, because it's undecidable, just like all but the most trivial problems in computer science. There will always be scenarios that neccessitate the manual use of a RAM-disk.

Comment: If it's undecidable by algorithms then it's also undecidable by humans.

Comment: But there is one perfectly valid use: Short-lived temporary files, for example when using tools that only work on files, not streams.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, anything that you need speed for, that you will use often. Its a way of increasing your apparent ram.

More info here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/how-do-i-use-a-ram-disk-to-help-speed-up-disk-intensive-applications/3430

Comment: I use a set of utilities often, but RAMDisk is volatile and will delete all files on it after reboot. Most utilities store their preferences in their folder in some sort of .ini file, so I would need: 1) a way to copy necessary files to RAMdisk automatically during system start, and 2) some mechanism to flush data from RAMDisk to HDD. This is the sort of troubles I don't like so I specifically want fuss-free speedup. Thus, the stuff that would be kept on disk should be regeneratable.

Comment: Covers it all so far. Paging will not work in most of the ramdisks, they come to late in the system. Even if RD could be paging, it would serve a small and useless purpose.  On a really stable system a person mightuse Ramdisk to "work with files", then transfer them out when done. Putting windows Own temps in them is very fast, But installs that break out into temps then reboot to install fail, making a mess. :-(   Browser caches (clearable:-) work wonders in them. Some browsers now use large ram caches for speed, some still get an advantage. Apps still have to be put ON it, so it is a toss-up

Answer (score 0):

I love my new RAM drive.  It makes my files and programs go at the speed of light when it should be crawling like a snail.  I love it!

I agree with the Jamie that you shouldn't make a RAM drive if you don't have enough RAM but if you have an i7 CPU and 32 gigs of RAM, a RAM drive is a great way to repurpose the extra RAM you'll never use.  At most, you'll probably need about 25 gigs of RAM to run your programs and games.  (And, I'm being generous.)  So, make a RAM drive of 7 gigs and you'll see your computer really flying.  So, contrary to the top answer, a RAM drive is NOT always a foolish use of RAM.

**The following is what you should put on your RAM drive.**

Resource-intensive programs that you close and open a lot throughout the work day.

A PDF editor is a good example because everyone needs one and all of them are pretty slow.  Let's say that you use Adobe Acrobat and you have not opened it yet on your computer.  You decide to open a 20 page PDF document with Adobe Acrobat.  On a normal computer, to open Adobe Acrobat and then have Adobe Acrobat open the 20 page PDF document, say it will take about 10 seconds.  (On many old computers, it takes longer.)  A RAM drive will actually decrease this time to 3 seconds.  So, you saved 7 seconds in your life!  Yay!

But, wait, you say.  Didn't the RAM drive have to mount the image of Adobe Acrobat when you booted your computer?  And, won't your computer have to save the image of Adobe Acrobat when you shut down?  Don't you have to consider this time wasted?  Yes, I agree.  Let's calculate it.

Since it took you 10 seconds to open Adobe Acrobat and then open the PDF document, it would probably take you 7 seconds to just open Adobe Acrobat.  This amount of time should be about the same amount of time that a RAM drives takes to mount an image of Adobe Acrobat.  Why?  The reason is because the computer is essentially mounting an image of Adobe when it "opens" Adobe Acrobat.  It is putting Adobe Acrobat into RAM so it can be used.  So, the cost of the RAM drive is 7 seconds during boot up and 7 seconds during shutdown.  That's 14 seconds.

Now, let's calculate how much time we saved by using a RAM drive.  We simply use the following formula:

Time Saved =
[Time Saved Using a RAM Drive] - [Time Wasted by the RAM Drive during Boot Up/Shutdown]

Time Saved = 7 - 14 = -7 seconds.

Uh oh.  The negative number means that we didn't save any time but the RAM drive instead cost us 7 seconds.  So, RAM drives are foolish, right?

Wait!  Say you now close Adobe Acrobat completely.  Why would you do this, you ask?  Well, you don't just want it taking up your valuable space on your monitor or task bar.  Screen real estate is really expensive.  There is so little of it.  Having useless programs, icons, or windows open messes up with my mind.  It really does!  So, you close Adobe Acrobat.  But, an hour later, you need to open another PDF file to read an abstract.  You read it and then close the entire program.  So, you saved 7 seconds.  Now, we broke even.  An hour later, you have to open up another PDF.  Do you see where we are going with this?  Every time we open and close Adobe Acrobat, we are saving 7 seconds!  If we happened to open and close 15 PDFs during one work day, we actually save time.  More precisely, we would save 84 seconds.

==> We saved about a minute and a half for the day.

Big deal you say sarcastically.  I actually think it is a big deal.  If you multiply this by 5 programs and 300 working days, the time you save is something.

But, far more important than the actual time saved is the suicidal thoughts.  The suicidal thoughts that run through your head as you wait for a program and its file to load up during those 10 seconds.  It really feels like torture.

Remember when we used to hard drives and we would have to wait for the computer to boot up and you felt like killing yourself?  SSDs made a huge difference.  RAM drives accomplishes the same goal but just throughout the work day.

Trust me.  They are awesome.